# Mustache if condition on date field

Tags: mustache

I am using Mustache template to render my data.
I have a date field "researchdate" and want conditional rendering, It should only render anchor tag if research date is not empty and is 2 weeks older or more.

```
{{#if researchDate}}
            <a href="/test" class="some-class" title="my title">R</a>
        {{/if}}
```

Here I can check if date is empty or not but how can I check if it is 2 weeks older or not?

Answer (score 0):

MustacheJS is a logic-less template system (those words are plastered over it's github page...). Your approach cannot be done. You have two options...

**Option 1**

Only render the view if object literal criteria is met.

```
var renderBool = ($(a.researchDate).val() !== null)?true:false;
if (renderBool){
   mustache.render(...);
}
```

**Option 2**

Assuming you're using JS flavour of Mustache, you can use jQuery to hide the view until the criteria is met. This would be done immediately *after* you have rendered your view.

```
var $researchDate = $(a.researchDate);
if (!$researchDate.val()){
   $researchDate.hide();
}
```

The above is not a copy/paste matter. You would have to add a class/ID to your anchor tag in view. This answer also assumes you're using Javascript flavour of MustacheJS which has a dependency on jQuery.